# Parse.initialize function prevents ionic app from loading only in ios emulator

Tags: ios, cordova, parse-platform, ionic-framework, emulation

I'm building an app using the Ionic framework. I'm working on integrating Parse as a backend service into the app. Everything works perfectly when I run the app in my browser or when I run the app in the emulator with live reload enabled. The issue is that when I run the app in the ios emulator without live reload enabled, something about the Parse.initialize() function call causes the app to fail. Without that line, everything works fine on the emulator (of course after I comment out all the Parse functionality). Essentially anything that takes place after I call Parse.initialize() never executes. I'm using the latest version of Parse (1.6.14) and Ionic (1.7.12).

Answer (score 0):

This is 1.6.14 problem. Please try this Javascript sdk:

http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-latest.js